# Is the Fighter's Improved Critical a roll with or without modifiers?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter

So, with the fighter's Improved Critical, do I add my modifiers to the roll or no?

Comment: You may also find your question addressed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80977/22566), and in this bank of questions and answers about [Fighter, Champion, and Critical hits](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+fighter+critical+champion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You must get a "natural" 19 or 20 to score a critical hit (or 18 at level 15+)

Although you would add your modifiers to the roll as long as you are attacking with something with which you are proficient (a martial or simple weapon, or an unarmed strike), you would only get a critical hit if you rolled a 19 or 20 on a die (before modifiers are added).

For example, if you attacked an Adult Red Dragon at level 3, using a short sword, when you had a strength of 16, and rolled a 15, your total for the attack roll would be:

- 15(roll)+3(strength)+2(proficiency)=  20

Your roll would hit the dragon (whose AC is 19), but it would not be a critical hit. The total was 20, but the unmodified roll was not (it was 15).

On the other hand, if you rolled a 19, your total would be:

- 19(roll)+3(strength)+2(proficiency)=24

Not only would this roll hit, it would be a critical hit because you rolled a 19 "naturally". And since a 19 is always a critical hit for your Fighter subclass, it would have been a hit even if the dragon's AC was higher than 24 (such as if it was a spellcaster, and cast Shield and Shield of Faith on itself, making its AC temporarily 26. Even this higher AC would be hit with a "natural" 19 by this fighter, due to Improved Critical).

Comment: I feel like the second situation is misleading - the addition of proficiency and modifiers is not necessary, since a critical is always a hit, regardless.

Comment: Good point @Ben. I've edited the answer to make the total modified roll relevant to that point.

Comment: I think you went the opposite direction haha. What I meant was that it should be as simple as "19 = hit. Now roll double damage"; modifiers and monster AC are not considered.

Answer (score 6):

A "critical hit" is always without modifiers.

If you roll a d20, and get an 18 on the die, if you have +2 modifier, that would make your overall roll a 20. But this is *not* a critical hit. You must get a 20 *on the die alone*.

The Champion's Improved Critical allows you to achieve this on a roll of 19 *on the die* as well as a 20, which is the standard.